# Hold any argument

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to define a function that holds arguments at given positions ?

Or to do something like HoldLast as a counterpart to HoldFirst ?

Comment: +1. I have no idea why people downvote this.

Comment: Could you explain a little more your question? Maybe due to I'm not English native I'm having problems to understand your problem...therefore, I think if you give more details or explain it other way, it's possible I understand it.

Comment: @TheCharlieMops this is a mathematica-specific question and has to do with the way expressions get evaluated (which is probably unfamiliar to people used to java, c etc). Perhaps this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldFirst.html will clarify things

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not do this directly in the sense that there isn't a `HoldN` attribute.
However, below there is a work-around that should be doing what you requested.

---

#### Proposed solution

One simple way is to define an auxiliary  function that will do the main work, and your "main" function (the one that will actually be called) as `HoldAll`, like so:

```
In[437]:= 
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[a_, b_, c_] :=
   faux[a, Unevaluated[b], c];
faux[a_, b_, c_] := Hold[a, b, c]

In[440]:= f[1^2, 2^2, 3^2]
Out[440]= Hold[1, 2^2, 9]
```

You don't have to expose the `faux` to the top level, can wrap everyting in `Module[{faux}, your definitions]` instead.

---

#### Automation through meta-programming

This procedure can be automated. Here is a simplistic parser for the function signatures, to extract pattern names (note - it is indeed simplistic):

```
splitHeldSequence[Hold[seq___], f_: Hold] := List @@ Map[f, Hold[seq]];

getFunArguments[Verbatim[HoldPattern][Verbatim[Condition][f_[args___], test_]]] := 
     getFunArguments[HoldPattern[f[args]]];

getFunArguments[Verbatim[HoldPattern][f_[args___]]] := 
     FunArguments[FName[f], FArgs @@ splitHeldSequence[Hold[args]]];

(*This is a simplistic "parser".It may miss some less trivial cases*)

getArgumentNames[args__FArgs] := 
   args //. {
     Verbatim[Pattern][tag_, ___] :> tag, 
     Verbatim[Condition][z_, _] :> z, 
     Verbatim[PatternTest][z_, _] :> z
   };
```

Using this, we can write the following custom definition operator:

```
ClearAll[defHoldN];
SetAttributes[defHoldN, HoldFirst];
defHoldN[SetDelayed[f_[args___], rhs_], n_Integer] :=
   Module[{faux},
      SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
      With[{heldArgs = 
         MapAt[
            Unevaluated,
            Join @@ getArgumentNames[getFunArguments[HoldPattern[f[args]]][[2]]],
            n]
         },
        SetDelayed @@ Hold[f[args], faux @@ heldArgs];
        faux[args] := rhs]]
```

This will analyze your original definition, extract pattern names, wrap the argument of interest in `Unevaluated`, introduce local `faux`, and make a 2-step definition - basically the steps we did manually. We need `SetDelayed @@ ..` to fool the variable renaming mechanism of `With`, so that it won't rename our pattern variables on the l.h.s. Example:

```
In[462]:= 
ClearAll[ff];
defHoldN[ff[x_,y_,z_]:=Hold[x,y,z],2]

In[464]:= ?ff
Global`ff
Attributes[ff]={HoldAll}

ff[x_,y_,z_]:=faux$19106@@Hold[x,Unevaluated[y],z]

In[465]:= ff[1^2,2^2,3^2]
Out[465]= Hold[1,2^2,9]
```

---

#### Notes

Note that this is trivial to generalize to a list of positions in which you need to hold the arguments. In general, you'd need a better pattern parser, but the simple one above may be a good start. Note also that there will be a bit of run-time overhead induced with this construction, and also that the `Module`-generated auxiliary functions `faux` won't be garbage-collected when you `Clear` or `Remove` the main ones - you may need to introduce a special destructor for your functions generated with `defHoldN`. For an alternative take on this problem, see my post in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/81da38250f225b95) thread (the one where I introduced the `makeHoldN` function).

Comment: I would like to vote twice, once for the solution and once for the ambiguous variable name faux  (is it f_auxiliary or the French faux = false/fake?)  ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd Funny - I don't know French at all (something I very much hope to remedy in this life). I must be very gifted in languages then :). Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @Leonid, Sjoerd: That thanks could be premature. He said he'd like to vote twice. But he did not say that he voted at all (would that be a faux vote?)

Comment: Merci Leonid, many things to learn from your meta-programming here!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do would be for example:

```
SetAttributes[f,HoldFirst];
f[{heldArg1_,heldArg2_},arg3_,arg4_,arg5_]:= Hold[arg3 heldArg1];
```

And this would allow to be able to have any mix of held and non held arguments.
HoldRest could be used similarly.